# 'Body Parse' error for 404 test in Mocha + Supertest

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest, body-parser

I am trying to write tests to ensure that my Express API is correctly returning the right HTTP status codes for various scenarios. I am using Mocha, and [Supertest](https://github.com/tj/supertest) for requests to the API in the tests. Right now I'm getting very unexpected results, which are detailed below.

Using: Express, body-parser, Sequelize, Mocha, Supertest

GET /users/:id

```
  models.User.find(req.params.id).complete(function(err, foundUser) {
    if (err) {
      logger.error(err, 'Error');
      return err;
    }

    console.log('user: ' + foundUser);
    if (foundUser != null) {
      res.json({ user: foundUser.getJsonRepresentation() });
    }
    else {
      res.status(404);
      res.json({ error: 'Not found' });
    }
  });
```

Tests for this method

```
it('responds with the right user', function(done){
      request(app)
        .get(apiPath + '/users/' + createdUser.id)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .expect(function(res) {
          res.body.user.id.should.equal(createdUser.id);
        })
        .expect(200, done);
    });

    it('responds with the right error code for non-existent resource', function(done) {
      request(app)
        .get(apiPath + '/users/1000')
        .expect(404, function(err, res) {
          console.log(err);
          console.log('Response: ' + res);
          done();
        });
    });
```

For the 404 test, I get this error: `{ [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 12, code: 'HPE_INVALID_STATUS' }` in the callback. The `res` is `undefined`.

I have tried several different syntax forms for this `expect` call: `.expect(404, function(err, res) {` and none of them have worked. I've also tried all the different syntax forms for this as well:

```
res.status(404);
res.json({ error: 'Not found' });
```

Can anyone offer some insight into what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the issue is in the following code snippet:

```
if (err) {
  logger.error(err, 'Error');
  return err;
}
```

It seems to be triggering the error but not actually returning it to the `supertest` client.

You can try to return the error to the client instead of only logging it, like this:

```
if (err) {
  logger.error(err, 'Error');

  res
    .status(500);
    .json({ error: error.message });
  return err;
}
```